# Unprivileged LXC fails to find subuid / subgid allocation

Tags: lxc, containers

When I run `lxc-usernsexec` I get the error message:

```
Failed to find subuid or subgid allocation
```

`lxc-create` and `lxc-start` work without any problems, but I would need to run `lxc-usernexec` to remove a container without being root.

The only google hit for the error message is in a [commit](https://lists.linuxcontainers.org/pipermail/lxc-devel/2018-August/018410.html), which added the error handling:

```
-       if (find_default_map()) {
-           fprintf(stderr, "You have no allocated subuids or subgids\n");
-           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
+       ret = find_default_map();
+       if (ret < 0) {
+           CMD_SYSERROR("Failed to find subuid or subgid allocation");
+           _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
```

This isn't very helpful, especially since the other tools are working well.

My subuids/subgids:

```
$ cat /etc/subuid
user:1000000:65536

$ cat /etc/subgid
user:1000000:65536
```